# What is the total area of the region bounded by the lines $y=x-1$ and $y=0$ over the interval $[0,2]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission exam 2019-20.*

Q) What is the total area of the region bounded by the lines $y=x-1$ and $y=0$ over the interval $[0,2]$?

(a) $\int_{0}^{2}(x-1)dx$

(b) $\int_{0}^{2}|x-1|dx$

(c) $2\int_{1}^{2}(1-x)dx$

(d) $2\int_{0}^{1}(x-1)dx$

**My attempt:**

Let the area of the region bounded by $y=x-1$ and $y=0$ in the interval $[0,2]$ is $A$. Now,

$$A=\int_{0}^{2}((x-1)-0)dx$$

$$A=\int_{0}^{2}(x-1)dx$$

So, I think the answer will be (a).

---

However, the correct answer according to the question bank is (b). I'm confused. Why did I get this wrong?

Comment: I suppose, more correct formulation is: total area of the finite regions bounded by $x=0$, $x=2$, $y=0$, $y=x-1$. Area of each region is positive quantity, therefore correct answer is (b).

Comment: Area (as opposed to *signed* area) is commonly understood as a nonnegative quantity. So, I'd choose (b) rather than (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a poorly worded question, that hinges on the phrase *total area bounded by the region*.  Implicit in the problem composer's intent is that (in effect) there is no such thing as a negative area.

This is clearly wrong, but does represent the problem composer's intent.  So, for $x < 1$, it is assumed that the region under the $x$-axis, that is bounded below by the line $y = x-1$ has a *positive* area, rather than a *negative* area.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking for the total area under the curve $y = x-1$. We know that an integral for the function returns the *signed* area under the curve. Since we want the total area we want to find the sum of the absolute area under the curve. Hope that the following diagrams help you:

[image]

Comment: I agree that this represents the problem composer's intent.  However, I see nothing in the phrase *total area* that precludes a region from having a negative area.

Comment: I presume that the question is ill-posed but in my experience doing admission tests (such as the OP is doing) this is what they usually *mean* be it conventionally interpreted as such is a different story